# Cannot find xpath element to click with webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I'm using the https://www.perlego.com/ website to do some scraping for books, my current problem is that i'm trying to search using the isbn Number of the book so the webdriver gets this following page for example https://www.perlego.com/search?query=9780717183241

However, using page inspection on the website, i cannot find the element that i can click on using webdriver

[image: image of page inspection]

the idea is to click on the book and load the page that comes with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code closes the cookies banner and clicks on the book link and opens it

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.perlego.com/search?query=9780717183241&tab=book&page=1&language=All%20languages&publicationDate=&topic=&publisher=&author=&format="

driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid*='Cookies']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-test-locator*='new-book']"))).click()
```

Comment: Hey prophet, quick question,, it is my first time seeing the expected conditions import, how did you know the css selectors since i couldn't really figure it out using page inspect?

Comment: We need WebDriverWait expected_conditions to wait for the page loaded and the elements to be clickable.  As about CSS Selectors. You need to learn how to create good locators. It's not difficult, but you have to learn and practice that. There are a lot of tutorials for that, try googling it

Comment: also last question, once waiting for the elements to be clickable, how would i return the link of the clickable item, the idea is once given a book it will scrape it's table of contents, i've managed that step, like i can scrape the table contents but i'm passing the actual url of the book whereas i want to do it dynmacally given the isbn

Comment: wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-test-locator*='new-book']")))` returns the web element. You can click it or extract it attribute. From your question I saw you want to click it and then to scrape a data there